# Silverlight error The type or namespace name 'MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

After Windows 10 update 1511 I try build my existing silverlight project and get this error

> The type or namespace name 'MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   for Web project generated file ProjectName.Web.g.cs

```
[DataMember()]
        [Display(Name="UserNameLabel", Order=0, ResourceType=typeof(RegistrationDataResources))]
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", ErrorMessageResourceName="ValidationErrorInvalidUserName", ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(ValidationErrorResources), MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds=-1)]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="ValidationErrorRequiredField", ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(ValidationErrorResources))]
        [StringLength(255, ErrorMessageResourceName="ValidationErrorBadUserNameLength", ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(ValidationErrorResources), MinimumLength=4)]
        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._userName;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._userName != value))
                {
                    this.OnUserNameChanging(value);
                    this.RaiseDataMemberChanging("UserName");
                    this.ValidateProperty("UserName", value);
                    this._userName = value;
                    this.RaiseDataMemberChanged("UserName");
                    this.OnUserNameChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

I haven't this error before I install update 1511.
I use Visual studio 2015 pro with update 1
anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: See relevant MSDN [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20e35456-996c-4193-adfc-79c5e90c22f0/the-type-or-namespace-name-matchtimeoutinmilliseconds-could-not-be-found?forum=silverlightdevtools)

Comment: it wasn't a Windows 10 update. For me it was a VS2015 Update 1 on a Win7 machine.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found a "BAD" workaround.

In the "Services/UserRegistrationService.cs" in the project.web code, comment out the "[RegularExpression(...)]" for CreateUser, RegistrationData.UserName, RegistrationData.Email.

From what I can tell they changed the why the code is generated.  If you have older copies of generated code you will find this property does not exist.

you can look here for the on-going issue.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2031887/generated-code-for-silverlight-references-matchtimeoutinmilliseconds-which-does-not-exist

Answer (score 2):

Open RIA Services released a fix today for this http://openriaservices.codeplex.com/workitem/84

Comment: Didn't seem to do a thing. Bad code is still generated.

Comment: I applied the fix to the wrong project... the generated code was being created from a DLL that was exposed to my client from the Silverlight Enabled web project. Had to apply fix to dll, NOT just the web project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem the other day and the project i am working on is still using `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices` and hasn't even migrated to Open RIA Services yet. So I had to go with another valid but a bit longer approach.

What you need to do is create a CustomValidation class that has a static validation method

```
public class CustomValidator
{
    public static ValidationResult IsNumberValid(int number, ValidationContext context)
    {
        ValidationResult result = ValidationResult.Success;

        if(number > 100) //Only an example
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Number is too large.", new string[]{"Number"});
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now in you metadata class add the CustomValidation attribute to your entity or in this case into the property with your type `CustomValidator` and the method name `IsNumberValid`

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(CustomValidator), "IsNumberValid")]
public int NumberToValidate {get; set;}
```

Hope this helps!